camera not rotating horizontally in unity
There is an issue with my code that doesn't allow me to look left and right based on my mouse movement. I can look up and down but i cannot look left and right. Note that i do have to use RotateTowards and MoveTowards as part of the requirements
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Input actions
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference moveAction;
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference lookAction;
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference sprintAction;

    // Character controller and camera
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Camera playerCamera;
    private Transform cameraTarget;  // Camera target for vertical rotation

    // Movement and rotation settings
    private float moveSpeed = 5f;
    private float sprintSpeed = 8f;   // Speed while sprinting
    private float rotationSpeed = 100f;
    private float lookSpeed = 2f;
    private float verticalRotation = 0f;

    public MazeManager mazeManager; // Reference to the MazeManager script

    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        playerCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();

        // Create an empty object to act as the camera target and position it above the player
        cameraTarget = new GameObject("CameraTarget").transform;
        cameraTarget.parent = transform; // Attach it to the player
        cameraTarget.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1.5f, 0); // Adjust the height as needed
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        moveAction.action.Enable();
        lookAction.action.Enable();
        sprintAction.action.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        moveAction.action.Disable();
        lookAction.action.Disable();
        sprintAction.action.Disable();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (mazeManager != null)
        {
            transform.position = mazeManager.GetMazeEntrancePosition();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("MazeManager is not assigned!");
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Read input values
        Vector2 moveInput = moveAction.action.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Vector2 lookInput = lookAction.action.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        // Handle horizontal rotation using RotateTowards
        float mouseX = lookInput.x * lookSpeed;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, transform.eulerAngles.y + mouseX, 0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Handle vertical rotation using the camera target
        verticalRotation -= lookInput.y * lookSpeed; // Inverted mouse Y movement for vertical look
        verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -80f, 80f); // Clamp to avoid extreme up/down look
        cameraTarget.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, 0f, 0f);

        // Ensure the camera looks at the camera target to follow the vertical rotation
        playerCamera.transform.position = cameraTarget.position; // Match the target position
        playerCamera.transform.localRotation = cameraTarget.localRotation; // Match the target rotation

        // Handle sprint action - Check if sprint (shift key) is pressed
        bool isSprinting = sprintAction.action.ReadValue<float>() > 0f;

        // If sprint is pressed, use the sprint speed
        float currentMoveSpeed = isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : moveSpeed;

        // Calculate movement direction
        Vector3 forward = playerCamera.transform.forward;
        forward.y = 0f; // Ignore vertical component
        forward.Normalize();

        Vector3 right = playerCamera.transform.right;
        right.y = 0f; // Ignore vertical component
        right.Normalize();

        // Calculate movement direction based on input
        Vector3 moveDirection = (forward * moveInput.y + right * moveInput.x).normalized;

        // Move the player using MoveTowards
        Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + moveDirection, currentMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        characterController.Move(newPosition - transform.position); // Apply movement
    }

    // Method to change movement speed
    public void SetMoveSpeed(float newSpeed)
    {
        moveSpeed = newSpeed;
    }
}

I added simple debug line to see what values im getting for horizontal mouse input (lookInput.x).
This is what I added to my Update() function.
// Debug the mouse input values for horizontal look
Debug.Log("Mouse X: " + lookInput.x);
I got this output:

It looks like the mouse input for the X-axis is registering correctly.

Well, you want it to look left and right but you are asking it to turn on a spit on the x axis.    that doesnt mean it will alter x values, it ,means it turns around on it so potentially it will go up/down/back/forth.. more like a foozball player, you were right in the start , your head forexample if you look left, rotates around Y

Im not sure what I need to fix

how you set the up/down look of your camera in awake is correct.. as explained how you are doing it on movement is not.. you are making it work like a foozball table top game player, eg like a rod though his side, now read up on what that command does and the answer should be obvious

Can i message you somewhere regarding this?Maybe discord or email?

Nope, Not unless you're going to be paying for tuition, you already know the answer, you've used it, i told you where you used it.. so, you should be able to achieve this on your own

Quick Solutions:
cam.transform.rotation = someValidQuaternionValue;

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));


cam.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));

Function:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mycamera :MonoBehaviour

{
[SerializeField]
private Camera cam;


public float Rotationing = 0;
public float Positioning = 0; 

void Update()
{
    
transform.Rotate(0, Rotationing, 0 * Time.deltaTime);  
transform.position = new Vector3(0, Positioning , 0);

}
}


using UnityEngine;

public class Camera_follow : MonoBehaviour{ 

public Transform Player;
public Vector3 offset;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position = Player.position + offset;
   
}


If all you are trying to do is rotate the object left or right depending on the mouse position multiplied by speed, something as simple as adding a Vector3 of the wanted change in the euler angles to the euler angle component of the transform.rotation like in the code below should work.
transform.rotation.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, lookInput.x *lookSpeed * 
Time.deltaTime, 0);

